# multiple date range selection my sql

Tags: mysql

I want to select multiple date ranges in mysql

where DATE between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-08', 
My requirement here is want data with multiple date ranges as below:
where DATE between ('2017-01-01' and '2017-01-08'),('2018-01-10' and '2018-01-15'),('2018-01-19' and '2018-01-20')

DO we have an option to do this in MYSQL?

Comment: Is there any logic to these date ranges or do you just want to hard code them every time you run the job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes like this for the first one

```
Select * from your_table where DATE >=  '2018-01-01' and DATE <= '2018-01-08'
```

and for the rest you mention it is like this:

```
 select * from your_table where 
 DATE >= '2017-01-01' and DATE <= '2017-01-08'
 or DATE >= '2018-01-10' and DATE <='2018-01-15'
 or DATE >= '2018-01-19' and DATE <= '2018-01-20'
```

I placed what we want to sort by in the `where` and separated each date range with the `or`

Comment: this should be what you want? if helpful accept answer for others to see and upvote if want